# Android app showing admob Interstitial ads only once

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a simple webview android app and i want to show admob Interstitial ads between the pages on the webview.

I'm using this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String url = "http://somepage.com";

    Boolean showProgressOnSplashScreen = true;

    WebView mWebView;
    ProgressBar prgs;
    RelativeLayout splash, main_layout;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-somenumbers38485838373");

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                // Call displayInterstitial() function
                //displayInterstitial();
            }
        });




        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
                Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        prgs = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        main_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

        // splash screen View
        if (!showProgressOnSplashScreen)
            ((ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarSplash)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        splash = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash);


        mWebView.loadUrl(url);



        mWebView.setFocusable(true);
        mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(
                this.getFilesDir().getPath() + this.getPackageName()
                        + "/databases/");

        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
                else {


                    view.loadUrl(url);

                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                if (prgs.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    prgs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                displayInterstitial();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                if (prgs.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    prgs.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // check if splash is still there, get it away!
                if (splash.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    splash.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // slideToBottom(splash);

            }

        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }




    public void displayInterstitial() {
        // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }

}
```

So, right now i'm loading the `displayInterstitial()` function inside `onPageStarted`.
It loading the ad after loading the first page on the app, but after that it's not showing anymore on the next pages.
How do i fix that so i'll have more ads between the other pages?
Iv'e set a cap on Admob to only show 1 ad per 3 minutes, but i have session times of 20+ minutes so it's a waste to show only 1 ad.

Comment: //displayInterstitial(); remove comment line

Comment: Ignore that function, i'm not really calling displayInterstitial there (that's why i have the comment line). I'm calling it under " public void onPageStarted". It's working well, but only once in a session and i want it between every page on the webview

Answer (score 0):

show your add in onload

request your add to load in displayInterstitial

```
public void displayInterstitial() {
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();    
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);        
        }

mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {

                   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            displayInterstitial();
                        }
                    }, 3000);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks ! But now i get ad every page instead of every 3 minutes like i configured on Admob for the ad unit... any idea why is that and how to fix it ?

Comment: yes ad interval will work on only single request called multiple time, we make new request every time so interval will ignored. to fix it you can manage interval from onAdclosed() in side Adlistner

Comment: click on error line ctrl+f1 to check error, you might be missing import statement